# PHP 7.0.0 with pthreads 3.1.5 on Windows can't start

Tags: php, pthreads, php-7

When trying to start PHP 7.0.0 (VC14 x64 Thread Safe 2015-Dec-03 20:07:26) with pthreads 3.1.5 (x64) on a Windows 7 system, I'm getting this error message:

```
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:8745 -c php.ini
PHP Fatal error:  The cgi-fcgi SAPI is not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
```

When dropping pthreads from php.ini, everything goes back to normal and PHP 7.0.0 works properly.

Any help to make it start with pthreads will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pthreads is only supported on the command-line from PHP 7 onwards:

> This release disables pthreads in all but the CLI SAPI.
>
> After many years of advising that multi-threading at the frontend doesn't make sense, I'm promoting the advice to hard and fast fact.

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/releases/tag/v3.0.6